# Issue with Google Analytics in Swift 2 or 3

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I have a problem with Swift 2 (Swift 3)  and Google Analytics.

This is the line with the problem:

```
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build())
```

Xcode tell's me:

> Cannot invoke 'send' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableDictionary!)'

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Update for Swift 3 (2016.10.19)**

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
let build = (GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as NSDictionary) as! [AnyHashable: Any]
tracker?.send(build)
```

Still an ugly approach, let me know if there's an cleaner conversion.

---

**Original**

Same here, struggling to resolve tons of errors.

What I did (deprecated):

```
var build = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createAppView().build() as [NSObject : AnyObject]
tracker.send(build)
```

Edit (2015)

Thanks to @George Poulos. . Recently they updated the options, now createAppView is deprecated, should use createScreenView instead.

```
var build = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [NSObject : AnyObject]
tracker.send(build)
```

Comment: @John I know. After 5 hours, finally see my app interface again. I did have used the function to convert to latest Swift syntax, still I had to resolved other 400 errors manually.

Comment: @ShaliLiu true stuff !

Comment: Back here after more than an year, but seeing the need of a cleaner alternative, please check my answer below. It extends GAIDictionaryBuilder for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the accepted answer:

Changed this:

```
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("UX", action: "User sign in", label: nil, value: nil).build())
```

To this:

```
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("UX", action: "User sign in", label: nil, value: nil).build()  as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Answer (score 5):

This might be a bit of an overkill, but I prefer creating a short extension and not need to type the castings every time:

In any swift file, paste the following code:

```
extension GAIDictionaryBuilder
{
    func buildSwiftCompatible() -> [NSObject:AnyObject]
    {
        return self.build() as [NSObject:AnyObject]
    }
}
```

Then you can call buildSwiftCompatible() instead of the usual build():

```
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().buildSwiftCompatible())
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I came up with.. Maybe it could help some of you. It's a struct you need to instantiate in every UIViewController, but it helps with the boilerplate.

```
import UIKit

struct Analytics {
    fileprivate let viewController: UIViewController
    fileprivate let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker

    init (forScreen viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }

    func startTracking () {
        let screenView = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as NSDictionary
        guard
            let tracker = tracker,
            let build = screenView as? [AnyHashable: Any]
        else { return }

        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: String(describing: viewController))
        tracker.send(build)
    }
}
```

---

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var analytics: Analytics = {
        return Analytics(forScreen: self)
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        analytics.startTracking()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For swift 3:

let build:NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()

tracker?.send(build as! [AnyHashable: Any])

Answer (score -2):

let build = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [NSObject : AnyObject]

tracker?.send(build)

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer.