# Swift 1.2: GAI -> Cannot invoke 'send' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableDictionary!)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-analytics, xcode6

I'm trying to convert this into Swift 1.2:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("ui_action", action: "app_launched",label:"launch",value:nil).build())
```

This is my best attempt:

```
let build = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("ui_action", action: "app_launched",label:"launch",value:nil)
        GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.send(build: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

But it keeps on resulting into this:

```
Cannot invoke 'send' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableDictionary!)'
```

Could someone help me out here? Please do not mark this as duplicate with this: Issue with [Issue with Google Analytics in Swift 2 or 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546605/issue-with-google-analytics-in-swift-1-2) and this: [Google Analytics not working with Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591930/google-analytics-not-working-with-swift-1-2-and-xcode-6-3)
I'm a Swift Noob and cannot apply the two questions to my problem even though they're conceptually quite close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ive just had a similar issue and found I wasn't instantiating the default tracker.

Are you calling this in the extension:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("XX-99999999-9")
```

Then I have this

```
var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("share_extension_tapped", action: "send_post", label: urlString, value: 0).build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```